# Ajax: Appending list-item at the top

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm calling a php processing file using ajax an appending the returned HTML usign the code below

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proc/process.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $("ul#lists").append(html);
        $("ul#lists li:last").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#flash").hide();
    }   
});
```

It appends a `<li></li>` item at the end of the ul#lists. I want the returned list-item `<li></li>` at the top of the lists instead of being appended at the last. How do I do that??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try the [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) function:

```
$("ul#lists").prepend(html);
$("ul#lists li:first").fadeIn("slow");
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fymtn/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "proc/process.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(retHtml){
    var oldhtml = $("ul#lists").html();
    $("ul#lists").html(retHtml + oldhtml);
    $("ul#lists li:first").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#flash").hide();
}   
});
```